# How to use spring batch to read JPA entities with associations

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-batch

I've been tasked with migrating data from a "legacy" web app that uses spring data JPA to a newer system. My initial thoughts were to use spring batch. I am using a `JpaPagingItemReader<LegacyEntity>` to read the legacy entities, a custom `ItemProcessor<LegacyEntity, NewDataDto>` to transform the entities and an `ItemWriter<NewDataDto>` to post the data via http rest call to the new system.

The entities have a lot of one to many associations. LegacyEntity has a one to many relationship with entityA which has a oneToMany relationship with entityB.

My problem is that the JpaPagingItemReader is driven by jpql. I want the reader to output one of each LegacyEntity with all associations fully loaded.  I looked into using a fetch join in jpql but it looks like it might not support nested associations and emits duplicates.

What's the best way to handle this? How would I handle this if I was using plain old jdbc?

Spring batch readers and processors all focus on processing one record at a time, only using paging under the hood so how would I normally read objects with toMany associations in batch?

Comment: Use an ETL tool for one time transfer and then schedule load transfer going forward.

Comment: The more I read about JPA the more I realize that it was never meant to handle queries with large resultSets of complex graphs that are never intended to be written back to the DB. JPA really excels at "read one thing, update the thing in memory,  save the thing  to db" flows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you'd use the driving query pattern.  Your `ItemReader` will read the ids (or the bare minimum entity).  The `ItemProcessor` will then enrich the item with whatever else is needed.  The `ItemWriter` will then have the full entity to write.  You can read more about this pattern in the Spring Batch documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders

Comment: But then I get the n +1 query problem. The problem is that the itemProcessor only works on one item at a time. I'd really like to be able to make more enrichment queries on the entire page before sending items to the processor.

Comment: The alternative is that your item is an aggregate (a `List` for example) that gets passed to the `ItemProcessor` and you do the looping.

Comment: Accepted as the answer is correct, but I ultimately went a different route. see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this with jdbc instead of jpa.

```
public class LegacyEntityReader extends JdbcPagingItemReader<LegacyEntity> {
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public LegacyEntityReader(DataSource dataSource, int pageSize) {
    //setup reader for loading legacyENtity without associations here
}

@Override
protected void doReadPage() {
    super.doReadPage();//this loads a page of root entities into a list exposed as a protected field: "results"
    List<Long> resultIds = results.stream().map(LegacyEntity::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

    //DO queries to load associations here where legacyEntity.id in resultIds
    //Then associate in memory with the results in the results field
}
}
```

JPA cannot be used to load entities  with associations in one jpa query using Paging. The query will inevitably yield duplicates and the deduplication will need to take place on the entire resultset in memory possibly leading to out of memory errors

This makes me sad :(.